# Can't install any package with npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I tried many ways to install packages with npm, including install with [sudo] and [--unsafe-perm], but it's not working.
Here is my error message:

[image: error message]

And here is the error log:

[image: error log]

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own, and text should be posted as text, not as images of text, or worse, links to images of text. On the plus side, it's not a link to a Word doc with a picture of text in it, so it could have been worse.

Comment: the error message actually says "this is probably not a problem with npm" - so, it's not a problem with npm

Comment: Hello, have you tried doing `npm install <package> --save` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the fist line of the error, you need to install the libffi package which is needed in this case to compile native C code, if on ubuntu:

```
apt install libffi-dev
```

Comment: I have installed libffi before and that's why I'm confused about the error message. It turns out that I didn't export PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Thanks for the helping though!